# What kind of complications would I face downgrading from MySQL 8 to MySQL 5?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysqldump, mysql-8.0, downgrade

Let's assume I wanted to downgrade to from MySQL 8 to MySQL 5.7. [I know this isn't supported](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/downgrading.html), but what kind of complications am I likely to encounter.

The docs say,

> The only supported alternative is to restore a backup taken ***before*** upgrading. It is therefore imperative that you backup your data ***before*** starting the upgrade process.

Let's say I buck the caveat, and dump on 8 and revive on 5.7? What should I expect? [Dumping on 5.x would product comments like](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/extensions-to-ansi.html)

```
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

These comments are documented as,

> If you add a version number after the `!` character, the syntax within the comment is executed **only if the MySQL version is greater than or equal to the specified version number**.

Are those kind of comments still produced by version 8? If so, what kind of scenarios would they not cover?

Comment: Did you run a v8 dump yourself? If so, are those kind of comments still produced?

Comment: 2 things i can think of: `Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'`, and the passwords from your users..

Comment: Can you tell the applications make use of [MySQL-8.0 features](https://mysqlserverteam.com/whats-new-in-mysql-8-0-generally-available/)?

Comment: I feel like this needs to be a self-answered question. As the person with the running MySQL 8 DB (presumably), can you JFDI on a newly provisioned 5.7 box and then post back the issues you saw?

Comment: @PeterVandivier i'm not the person running it, i'm asking a pretty abstract question i figure someone has tried this. $work is building something that does this, and i'm doing preliminary research.

Comment: Was this a recent upgrade to 5.7 -- not likely to have added 8.0-only features?  Or a fresh install in 8.0 -- likely to have accidentally or deliberately used new features?

Comment: Use the https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration.html from mysql Workbench, connect both databases and transfer the data and routines. Check if views procedures and fucntions have window fiunction in it that will not work in 5.7 and zthe users must be transfered manually